# uitableview will not scroll when keyboard appears on the first launch of view. Later it works properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

There are many answers about moving the `UITableView` when keyboard appears but my problem is something different. I am able to move the `UITableView` when keyboard appears but the only problem i am facing is `UITableView` will not scroll when i visit the view for the first time, but when i press back button and revisit the view then its working properly. I am confused it is the same code which is working every time expect the first time i visit the view. I am using UITableView in xib. I tried setting contentInset but no use. Any help will be really appreciated.

I am posting an image which shows the problem i am facing

[image]

Below is my code.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

     //keyboard observers
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];


        //tap on tableview or whole view
        UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

      //scroll to bottom of conversation
        [self scrollToBottomOfConversation];

    }


    - (void)scrollToBottomOfConversation
    {
        CGFloat yOffset = 0;

        if (_chatConversationTableView.contentSize.height > _chatConversationTableView.bounds.size.height) {
            yOffset = _chatConversationTableView.contentSize.height - _chatConversationTableView.bounds.size.height;
        }

        [_chatConversationTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, yOffset) animated:NO];
    }

    - (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
    {

        NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
        CGSize size = [[userInfo objectForKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(_chatConversationTableView.frame.origin.x,
                                  _chatConversationTableView.frame.origin.y,
                                  _chatConversationTableView.frame.size.width,
                                  _chatConversationTableView.frame.size.height - size.height);
        _chatConversationTableView.frame = frame;


        CGRect framee = containerView.frame;//containerView is my subView which holds the textbox and send button
        framee.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - framee.size.height - size.height;
        containerView.frame = framee;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        //scroll to bottom of conversation
        [self scrollToBottomOfConversation];


    }


    -(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
    {

        NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
        CGSize size = [[userInfo objectForKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
        _chatConversationTableView.frame = CGRectMake(_chatConversationTableView.frame.origin.x,
                                          _chatConversationTableView.frame.origin.y,
                                          _chatConversationTableView.frame.size.width,
                                          _chatConversationTableView.frame.size.height + size.height);

        CGRect frame = containerView.frame;
        frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - frame.size.height;
        containerView.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];



    }
```

Comment: Write "[self scrollToBottomOfConversation]"in the viewDidAppear Method rather then viewDidLoad method.

Comment: @yagneshdobariya i have already tried this but no use.

Comment: When keyboard appear change the bottom constraint of table...

Comment: because the table hide due to keyboard.

Comment: @SaurabhJain, thanks for reply if the keyboard hides the tableview it should not work anytime but the code is working fine when i revisit the view.  I am not using any constraints.

Comment: use [self layoutIfNeeded] when keyboard appear

Comment: layoutIfNeeded does not help.@SaurabhJain

Comment: take the layout of bottom constraint of table view and change it value to the height of keyboard when keyboard appear.

Comment: Thanks for your support. @SaurabhJain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the keyboard notification code in main thread solved my problem. This helped me to overcome the issue. I think for some reason the tableview frame size was not updating when keyboard appears. Posting the code so that it may help others.

```
 - (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //This code will run in the main thread:

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize size = [[userInfo objectForKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(_chatConversationTableView.frame.origin.x,
                              _chatConversationTableView.frame.origin.y,
                              _chatConversationTableView.frame.size.width,
                              _chatConversationTableView.frame.size.height - size.height);
    _chatConversationTableView.frame = frame;


    CGRect framee = containerView.frame;
    framee.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - framee.size.height - size.height;
    containerView.frame = framee;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

        //scroll to bottom of conversation
        [self scrollToBottomOfConversation];


         });
}
```